# How do I get push data from Firebase to Arduino?

Tags: c++, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

When add new device through the app, added the details with pushing. And I searched through Google but could not find a solution

I could get the json value from firebase.

```
{"-MjPZs2_4wAg-81-y910":{"Place":"asd","State":"ON","Title":"szd - 1"},"-MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq":{"Place":"asasjdasd","State":"OFF","Title":"UDITHA - 2"},"-MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo":{"Place":"asasjdasd","State":"OFF","Title":"Gate - 3"},"-MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq":{"Place":"asasjdasd","State":"OFF","Title":"උදිත - 4"}}
```

This code I used and it worked but that static.

```
// String input;

StaticJsonDocument<512> doc;

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, input);

if (error) {
  Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
  Serial.println(error.f_str());
  return;
}

JsonObject MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910 = doc["-MjPZs2_4wAg-81-y910"];
const char* MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910_Place = MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910["Place"]; // "asd"
const char* MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910_State = MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910["State"]; // "ON"
const char* MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910_Title = MjPZs2_4wAg_81_y910["Title"]; // "szd - 1"

JsonObject MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq = doc["-MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq"];
const char* MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq_Place = MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq["Place"]; // "asasjdasd"
const char* MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq_State = MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq["State"]; // "OFF"
const char* MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq_Title = MjP_kgFyDFPZMlsTZpq["Title"]; // "UDITHA - 2"

JsonObject MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo = doc["-MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo"];
const char* MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo_Place = MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo["Place"]; // "asasjdasd"
const char* MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo_State = MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo["State"]; // "OFF"
const char* MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo_Title = MjQ0t2JKQynjM6iMwfo["Title"]; // "Gate - 3"

JsonObject MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq = doc["-MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq"];
const char* MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq_Place = MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq["Place"]; // "asasjdasd"
const char* MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq_State = MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq["State"]; // "OFF"
const char* MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq_Title = MjQ1MYaMn8atIsE6lmq["Title"]; // "උදිත - 4"
```

Firebase database -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a loop, you would iterate over each entry and processing them as needed.

```cs
if(doc.length() > 0){
          JsonArray& nodes = jsonBuffer.parseArray(doc);
          if (!nodes.success()) {
            Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
            jsonBuffer.clear();
          }else{
            int node_length = nodes.size(); 
            for(int i=0; i<node_length;i++){
              Serial.printf("node-%i\nValue : ",i );
              String value = nodes[i]["Place"].as<const char*>();
              String state = nodes[i]["State"].as<const char*>();
              Serial.println(value);
              Serial.print("State : ");
              Serial.println(state); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Error => ( `if(doc.length() > 0){` ->'class ArduinoJson6184_91::StaticJsonDocument<512u>' has no member named 'length' AND `JsonArray& nodes = JsonBuffer.parseArray(doc)` -> JsonBuffer is a class from ArduinoJson 5. Please see https://arduinojson.org/upgrade to learn how to upgrade your program to ArduinoJson version 6 )

Comment: seems that error is from a newer version of ArduinoJson, you will need to upgrade the code per the upgrade guide. specifically removing the `&` - this is documented here: https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/upgrade/

Comment: I'm using version 6 but your some code version 5. if you can please edit right answer. thank you very much